# How to play music file with 2 activities continuely

Tags: android

As the title, I searched but couldn't find out.

I want to play 1 mp3 file in Activity A, when Intent to Activity B, the .mp3 still continue play and if I intent to Activity C, that .mp3 will stop?

Comment: Ask your questions one at a time (I removed the second one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a service for playing mp3 file,you can start play it in ActivityA,and stop it after ActivityC started.For your second question please describe it by more details or post your code about that in your question.

Comment: Hi Aolphn, I'm new about Android so please explain detail how to create a service. Thanks

Comment: here is android doc about Service https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/app/Service, you can check it.